# Is it still possible to hatch Electabuzz, Jynx, Pikachu and Magmar?

Tags: pokemon-go

Since a recent update, it is possible to hatch Pichu, Togepi, Cleffa, Igglybuff, Magby, Smoochum and Elekid from eggs. But since that update, I have never seen any Electabuzz, Jynx, Magmar and Pikachu hatch from my eggs, while it was the case before this update.

Is it still possible to hatch one of those four Pokémon nowadays?

Comment: @Vemonus Aaaaah. Was sure I have seen this question somewhere, but couldn't find it again. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. I asked a dupe a few days ago, as well.